# Сумма элементов массива, расположенных между первым и последним нулевыми элементами (Цикл в delphi)

Tags: delphi

Дан одномерный целочисленный массив. Найти: сумму элементов массива, расположенных между первым и последним нулевыми элементами.

```
  procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
a:array [1..n] of integer;
i,b:integer;
begin
b:=0;
for i := 1 to b do
a[i]:=strtoint(StringGrid1.Cells[i-1,0]);
for i := 1 downto b do
begin
b := b + a[i];
end;
edit1.Text:=inttostr(b);
end;

end.
```

Не могу найти ошибку. Помогите найти.

Comment: Вы не поняли задание. Нулевые элементы - это элементы, значение которых равно нулю.  
По коду. Все совсем плохо. Воспользуйтесь отладчиком.

Comment: Ощущение, что Вы вообще не понимаете, что написали в коде...

Первый цикл не выполнится, т.к. 1 до 0, во втором прибавится значение элемента, которые не был определён, может 0, может мусор, Что же вы ожидаете на выходе?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибки построения алгоритма, т.е. Вы, наверное, не совсем поняли суть задания:

```
procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  a:array [1..n] of integer; // здесь n - глобальная константа размер массива
  i:integer;
  b:integer; // подсчёт суммы элементов
  firstZero,lastZero: integer; // индекс первого и последнего 0 в массиве
begin
  b:=0;
  firstZero:=0;
  lastZero:=0;
  for i := 1 to n do
  begin
    a[i]:=strtoint(StringGrid1.Cells[i-1,0]); // Это заполнение массива элементами из StringGrid
    if (a[i]=0) then
    begin
      lastZero:=i; // присваиваем индекс каждого 0, в итоге тут будет индекс последнего 0
      if (firstZero=0) then // находим только первый 0
        firstZero:=i;
    end;
  end;
  if lastZero>firstZero then // если индекс последнего 0 больше чем индекс первого, тогда цикл подсчёта, иначе считать нечего
    for i := firstZero do lastZero do
      b := b + a[i];
  edit1.Text:=inttostr(b);
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Давайте выработаем план действий, а осуществлять его будете сами.

1. Определим стартовый индекс поиска. Для этого двигаемся от начала массива до первого нуля и выходим из цикла. Поверяем, не является ли стартовый индекс концом массива. Если да, возвращаем нуль.
2. Определим финишный индекс поиска. Для этого двигаемся от конца массива до первого нуля и не выходим из цикла. Поверяем, не является ли финишный индекс началом массива или не равен ли он стартовому. Если да, возвращаем нуль. Если нет, двигаемся дальше до старта, собирая по дороге сумму.